# Is It possible to create BCP without mentioning input file name?

Tags: bcp

```
BULK INSERT NECCOI_DB.dbo.ALL_Stores
    FROM 'C:\TestingforAutomation\AllStores.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
        ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
        FIRSTROW=2
    )
```

My bat file is like this:

```
bcp NECCOI_DB.dbo.ALL_Stores in C:\TestingforAutomation\AllStores.csv -Uvm -PMadhu@9515 -SBLLT-5CD124JQHQ -c -F2 -t ","  
TIMEOUT /T 60
```

It is working fine without any issues ,but this script have to work without mentioning csv file name means with any csv file it should work...
so i have changed my script to this:

```
bcp NECCOI_DB.dbo.ALL_Stores in C:\TestingforAutomation\*.csv -Uvm -PMadhu@9515 -SBLLT-5CD124JQHQ -c -F2 -t ","  
TIMEOUT /T 60
```

It's giving error like this:

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
> for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

can anyone guide me to fix this ?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this within the BCP command.
To bulk copy many files, you'll need to write code to cycle through the list of files you want loaded and build a new bcp or bulk insert statement for each file to be loaded.

Neither the BCP utility nor the BULK INSERT t-sql command can accept wildcards.